# Get Text and store into Excel sheet using Groovy Script in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to get value from xml in soapui tool and store those data into Excel sheet. I used groovy script in SoapUI tool.

If Response have multiple output and these output store in excel sheet. Like LocationName and CustCity333Name have twice, so these output should store into excel sheet. Please help me to resolve this issue

```
<ns10:Location>
           <ns10:LocationId>
              <ns5:RowId>7080013</ns5:RowId>
           </ns10:LocationId>
           <ns10:LocationDetails>
              <ns10:AuditElement/>
              <ns10:EffectiveDate/>
              **<ns10:LocationName>REMOVEDEPENDENCY004</ns10:LocationName>**
             <ns10:RailIncData/>
              **<ns10:CustCity333Name>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Name>**
              <ns10:CustCity333Id>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Id>
              <ns10:CustCity333StateCode>TN</ns10:CustCity333StateCode>
              <ns10:ParentCIFDetails/>
           </ns10:LocationDetails>
        </ns10:Location>
        <ns10:Location>
           <ns10:LocationId>
              <ns5:RowId>7080018</ns5:RowId>
           </ns10:LocationId>
           <ns10:LocationDetails>
              <ns10:AuditElement/>
              <ns10:EffectiveDate/>
              **<ns10:LocationName>REMOVEDEPENDENCY004</ns10:LocationName>**
              <ns10:RailIncData/>
              **<ns10:CustCity333Name>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Name>**
              <ns10:CustCity333Id>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Id>
              <ns10:CustCity333StateCode>TN</ns10:CustCity333StateCode>
              <ns10:ParentCIFDetails/>
           </ns10:LocationDetails>
```

Comment: Is the problem to extract the data from xml? or writing into excel?

Comment: Yes Rao, Data need to be extract and store into Excel sheet
Expected Result be like below in Excel

REMOVEDEPENDENCY004 OAKLAND
REMOVEDEPENDENCY004 OAKLAND

Comment: Do you have anything / script that store data in excel? Are you just stick to excel or open to csv too?

Comment: I dont have any script. Just i using excel or csv

Comment: What if there are more `LocationDetails`, the number of column data increases, right? what are you trying to achieve by storing data in there?

Comment: Yes sir, it will increase, we have 300k records and all response need to store in Excel and later move to DB.

Comment: The question is the data should be in rows or in columns?

Comment: Data should be in Rows
Eg: 
REMOVEDEPENDENCY004     OAKLAND
REMOVEDEPENDENCY004     OAKLAND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE:

- Since you mentioned excel or csv is fine, below script uses `csv` format.
- The data you provided is not well-formed. Modified a bit to make it well-formed.
- Also using `rowId` for identification in the row. You may remove if you do not wish.

**Groovy Script**

```
//Provide / edit file path  for csv  file in the below
def fileName = '/tmp/locationData.csv'

def xml = """<root xmlns:ns10='url1' xmlns:ns5='url2'> <ns10:Location>
           <ns10:LocationId>
              <ns5:RowId>7080013</ns5:RowId>
           </ns10:LocationId>
           <ns10:LocationDetails>
              <ns10:AuditElement/>
              <ns10:EffectiveDate/>
              <ns10:LocationName>REMOVEDEPENDENCY004</ns10:LocationName>**
             <ns10:RailIncData/>
              <ns10:CustCity333Name>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Name>**
              <ns10:CustCity333Id>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Id>
              <ns10:CustCity333StateCode>TN</ns10:CustCity333StateCode>
              <ns10:ParentCIFDetails/>
           </ns10:LocationDetails>
        </ns10:Location>
        <ns10:Location>
           <ns10:LocationId>
              <ns5:RowId>7080018</ns5:RowId>
           </ns10:LocationId>
           <ns10:LocationDetails>
              <ns10:AuditElement/>
              <ns10:EffectiveDate/>
              <ns10:LocationName>REMOVEDEPENDENCY004a</ns10:LocationName>**
              <ns10:RailIncData/>
              <ns10:CustCity333Name>OAKLAND1</ns10:CustCity333Name>**
              <ns10:CustCity333Id>OAKLAND</ns10:CustCity333Id>
              <ns10:CustCity333StateCode>TN</ns10:CustCity333StateCode>
              <ns10:ParentCIFDetails/>
           </ns10:LocationDetails>
</ns10:Location>
</root>"""
def parsedXml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def data = parsedXml.'**'.findAll{ it.name() == 'Location'}.inject([]){list, loc -> list << new Expando(
     rowId: loc?.LocationId?.RowId?.text(),
     locationName: loc?.LocationDetails?.LocationName?.text(),
     cityName: loc?.LocationDetails?.CustCity333Name?.text()); list }
if (0< data.size()) {
  def sb = new StringBuffer(data[0].properties.keySet().join(',')).append('\n')
  data.collect { sb.append(it.properties.values().join(',')).append('\n')}
  new File(fileName).write(sb.toString())
} else {
  println 'No records found'
}
```

You can check how data is generated quickly online <kbd>[Demo](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5104251139260416)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much Rao, Code is working
Appreciate your effort.